# Allow typing of time when Jquery datepicker are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have an HTML textbox that uses a datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= txtDateFrom.ClientID  %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' });
    });
```

I would like users to optionally type in a time as well.  Currently users can edit the textbox, but only the date part.

Comment: There are no timepickers included in jQueryUI, so you'd need to use a third party plugin, such as this: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
     $("#<%= txtDateFrom.ClientID  %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', constrainInput: false });
});
</script>
```

constrainInput: false allows anything can be typed in the text field

Answer (score 1):

As Rory commented already, there is no time included in jquery ui datepicker plugin, but using the one created by Trent Richardson (http://trentrichardson.com) you could achieve what you are looking for.

I am using this very plugin often in various projects, I am used to have a `date` class initialized somewhere in a Master view:

```
    $('.date').datetimepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: '<%:Url.Image("calendar.gif")%>',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        ampm: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss TT'
    });
```

here is a snapshot i just took, note it has two date fields, the input is completely free type, time is added either manually or using scrolls under the calendar inside popup:

[image: datetimepicker plugin usage]